# Putty key, Works on Win10, but not on Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Tags: server, ssh, git, putty, gitlab

I have made a public and private pair keys with puttygen on Windows and uploaded to the server. And my private key works like a charm on Windows 10(git not installed). When I use Putty for linux ubuntu(git installed) I can't use it. I am going to pull a project on gitlab from a server, so I need to use my ***name.ppk*** file to login to the server located at ***ipaddress@host.com***.

Question: How can I login using my ***name.ppk*** file located on **~/Desktop**, on terminal?

Comment: Did you convert the key to OpenSSH format? See for example [How to convert ppk to SSH key using PuTTY Key Generator](https://www.simplified.guide/putty/convert-ppk-to-ssh-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the key to OpenSSH format (note this will **overwrite your existing SSH key if you have one**)

```
sudo apt install putty-tools
mkdir ~/.ssh
puttygen ~/Desktop/name.ppk -O private-openssh -o ~/.ssh/id_dsa
puttygen ~/Desktop/name.ppk -O public-openssh -o ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
chmod 666 ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

Now you can simply use `ssh` to connect to your server in a regular terminal:

```
ssh user@host
```

Also note that if you open your file browser (nautilus, dolphin, etc.) you can use the GUI to browse your server by entering:

```
sftp://user@host
```

Where `sftp://` means FTP over SSH in this case. There is also the `fish://` protocol which also uses SSH but doesn't use any FTP like commands which may be faster.

Comment: What if I have git key in this location? ./ssh/id_dsa.

Comment: Then you should use that key to SSH into your server instead or use `ssh -i path_to_key user@host` to manually specify the key (although you won't get as eay of a GUI interaction) - Also there is no such thing as a "git key" in this contex (unless you are doing signed commits) it's an OpenSSH key

Comment: To get the public key line you would add to your server's authorized_keys file run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`